# Calculate cache hit rate

Tags: caching, assembly, memory-management, mips

I am doing an older exam of the course, having a hard time to get grip of calculating cache miss hit rate, here is the question:

Suppose you have a 32-bit processor with a direct mapped instruction cache. The capacity of the cache is 2048 bytes and there are 256 sets. Assume that a program loop contains 5 instructions, including a conditional jump instruction, which is the last of the 5 instructions. The other 4 instructions are not jump instructions. The ﬁrst instruction in the loop is located at memory address 0x40001000. What is the instruction cache hit rate when executing the loop 10 times? Does the example show temporal locality, spatial locality, or both?

The answer should be 47/50 hit rate.

My try does not come far, what I can here is by doing `2048/256` we get 8 bytes block size, but I have no clue how to calculate the hit rate, where to start, anyone have an explaination how this can be calculate would be much appreciated. Mean while... I am seeking other topics try to understand.

Comment: It's obviously going to be `/50` since you have 10 iterations of 5 instructions. The entire loop occupies `5*4=20` bytes which is 3 cache lines. Hence the first 3 accesses are misses and the other 47 are hits.

Comment: @Jester can you explain abit more what is `5*4=20` byte which is 3 cache lines, I did not quit understand.

Comment: Each instruction is 4 bytes (32 bits). So 20 in total. Since each block is 8 bytes you need 3.

Comment: @jester Got it, thanks!